# What is the PHP way to check isset() and greater than 5?

Tags: php

When I run a simple if statement and the key is not set it fails, I want to know what is the best way to check if the key is set and greater than 5. This is what I have now:

```
if (isset($a['key']) {
    if ($a['key'] > 5) {
        foo;
    }
}
```

I know there is a prettier way of doing this.

Simply checking for greater than 5 results in an error when not set.

```
if ($a['key'] > 5) {
    foo;
}
```

Comment: What is `key`? Is it a constant you defined somewhere? This code is likely to produce an error, unless you meant `$a[$key]`, or `$a['key']`, etc. But, you can do `if(isset($a['key']) && $a['key'] > 5) { ... }`

Comment: ```if(isset($a['key']) && $a['key'] > 5)```

checks ```$a['key']``` first and errors.

Comment: That's better  So yeah, `if (isset($a['key'] && $a['key'] > 5)`, or `if ($a['key'] ?? 0 > 5)`, etc.

Comment: It checks `isset()` first and doesn't trigger an error: https://3v4l.org/BMd4V

Comment: Just rechecked you are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP7.1

```
 if ($a['key'] ?? 0 > 5) {
     //  $a['key'] is set and also greater than 5
 }
```

Comment: This is interesting syntax. Do you have a source I can read further on how this works?

Comment: Sure , and it's rmeeber me it's since 7.0 note 7.1
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php 

"The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not null; otherwise it returns its second operand."

if left side of ?? is unset or null, then the right side is used